# Get sum of subarray column for indexed rows

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of customers/people with a subarray of projects pertaining to that customer. Projects come in two types "typeJob" or "typePipeline". I need to sum the values of individual columns in the projects subarray (specifically columns 5, 6, 7 - representing revenue for month 1, month 2, and month 3) by Client.

I have tried various possible avenues including the one below, but I seem to always end up either testing if the condition is satisfied for the array as a whole rather than for each row - or if I go the way of for each loops generate errors because either there's an array/single value mismatch or the condition just doesn't do anything.

Here is what I have tried most recently. It works in the sense that it checks if "typeJob" is in the array but then sums all rows (even those without "typeJob") if "typeJob" is found for any of the Client's projects. I want to exclude rows where "typeJob" is not found.

```
foreach ($arrays as $row) {
$indexJob = array_search('typeJob', array_column($row['projects'],0));
  if ($indexJob !== false) {
  $job_total1[$row['Client']] = array_sum(array_column($row['projects'],5));
  $job_total2[$row['Client']] = array_sum(array_column($row['projects'],6));
  $job_total3[$row['Client']] = array_sum(array_column($row['projects'],7));
  }
}
```

And here is the array:

```
(
    [331] => Array
        (
            [KeyAccountID] => 1234
            [KeyAccountName] => John Lennon
            [ClientID] => 9999
            [Client] => BBC
            [projects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => typePipeline
                            [1] => 915
                            [2] => Zyxeldy
                            [3] =>  
                            [4] =>  
                            [5] => 15000
                            [6] => 
                            [7] => 
                            [8] =>  
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => typeJob
                            [1] => 956
                            [2] => Awesome project, Step 1 
                            [3] =>  
                            [4] =>  
                            [5] => 1833.3333
                            [6] => 1833.3333
                            [7] => 1833.3333
                            [8] =>  
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => typePipeline
                            [1] => 957
                            [2] => Awesome project, Step 2 
                            [3] =>  
                            [4] =>  
                            [5] => 7000
                            [6] => 
                            [7] => 
                            [8] =>  
                        )

                )

        )

    [344] => Array
        (
            [KeyAccountID] => 1234
            [KeyAccountName] => John Lennon
            [ClientID] => 9998
            [Client] => ABC
            [projects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => typePipeline
                            [1] => 487
                            [2] => CRM integration
                            [3] =>  
                            [4] =>  
                            [5] => 
                            [6] => 98750
                            [7] => 98750
                            [8] =>  
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => typeJob
                            [1] => 839
                            [2] => Data Warehouse
                            [3] =>  
                            [4] =>  
                            [5] => 
                            [6] => 11643.0601
                            [7] => 
                            [8] =>  
                        )

                )

        )

    [350] => Array
        (
            [KeyAccountID] => 1236
            [KeyAccountName] => Ringo Starr
            [ClientID] => 9997
            [Client] => XYY
            [projects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => typeJob
                            [1] => 867
                            [2] => Data Mining
                            [3] =>  
                            [4] =>  
                            [5] => 10000
                            [6] => 
                            [7] => 
                            [8] =>  
                        )

                )

        )

    [351] => Array
        (
            [KeyAccountID] => 1235
            [KeyAccountName] => Poul McCartney
            [ClientID] => 9996
            [Client] => XYZ
            [projects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => typePipeline
                            [1] => 715
                            [2] => XYZ, CSM
                            [3] =>  
                            [4] =>  
                            [5] => 22083.3333
                            [6] => 22083.3333
                            [7] => 22083.3333
                            [8] =>  
                        )

                )

        )
etc.
```

Comment: Please post your exact desired output from your sample input.  Always post your sample input as json or the displayed value of `var_export()` so that volunteers can help you faster and more accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the `$row['projects']` array before summing the values:

```
foreach ($arrays as $row) {
    $typeJobs = array_filter($row['projects'], function ($v) { return $v[0] == 'typeJob'; });
    $job_total1[$row['Client']] = array_sum(array_column($typeJobs,5));
    $job_total2[$row['Client']] = array_sum(array_column($typeJobs,6));
    $job_total3[$row['Client']] = array_sum(array_column($typeJobs,7));
}
```

Comment: You might find @NigelRen solution to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It may be quicker to just loop through them and keep a running total...

```
foreach ($arrays as $row) {
    $totals = [0,0,0];
    foreach ( $row['projects'] as $project )    {
        if ( $project[0] == 'typeJob' ) {
            $totals[0] += $project[5];
            $totals[1] += $project[6];
            $totals[2] += $project[7];
        }
    }
    $job_total1[$row['Client']] = $totals[0];
    $job_total2[$row['Client']] = $totals[1];
    $job_total3[$row['Client']] = $totals[2];
}
```

it doesn't look as slim as using the `array_...` methods, but this only processes the array once instead of once for each call.

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen Efficiency is not a primary concern (small data amount) but I will give it a try.

Comment: @Mads please respect went volunteers not only provide working solutions, but also bother to optimize the process.  You may not have a lot of data to process this time, but once you have this in your project, there is a chance that you will copy-paste it elsewhere for a scenario that DOES have more data.  Best practices is important to embrace.